# How to use tags of counter in Grafana?

Tags: java, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, druid

I have such problem: i need to use tags of Counter

Here Im adding tags to counter:

```
Counter.Builder counterBuilder = Counter.builder("kafka_messages_total");

    public void addMoreInfo(Map<String, String> messageInfo) {
            messageInfo.forEach((key, value) ->
                    counterBuilder.tag(key, value)
            );
            counterBuilder
                    .register(meterRegistry)
                    .increment();
        }
```

output from terminal (actuator/prometheus):
kafka_messages_total{product_fabric_code="A", scenario_code="B"}

I want to filter graph by this tags. I've tried to create variables in grafana but nothing works.
If you need additional information tell me.